# Data truncation: Data too long for column 'codpre' at row 1 Como puedo arreglarlo

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Pues como bien dice en el título me da ese error al insertar datos en mi base de datos de java. Solo me da fallo ese es un varchar de 5 le meto 5 y no funciona le meto menos por ejemplo 4 y si me funciona, pero necesito que me funcione metiendole 5 he intentado cambiar a varchar 10 y me pasa igual y luego lo he establecido a varchar 5 y siempre lo mismo no me deja 5 justo solo menos, que puedo hacer?

Le meto valores como si fuera un codigo ckr01 si es asi de 5 me lo rechaza si es de 4 lo acepta

Comment: Según el encodaje del valor, algo que _aparentemente_ tiene `n` caracteres, podría tener más, sobre todo si se trata de caracteres especiales. ¿Será tu caso? Sería interesante que des ejemplo de los valores que está rechazando, editando la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Qué valores te rechaza? ¿Tiene algún carácter especial?

Comment: ¿Podrías proporcionar información  del dato que quieres insertar, y del detalle de la columna (tipo de dato, extensión, nombre) etc?

Comment: No tiene caracteres especiales es un varchar de 5 y le meto como si fuera un codigo ckr01 si le meto 5 justo me lo rechaza si le meto 4 me lo acepta

Comment: En lugar de "como puedo arreglarlo" trata (en general) de preguntarte "que está pasando".

Comment: "si le meto 5 justo me lo rechaza si le meto 4 me lo acepta " Muestranos un ejemplo. Es imposible diagnosticar problemas si no nos das información.

Comment: ¿Cuántos caracteres crees que hay ahí: `foobar`?... y aquí: `foo᠎bar` También: `foo​bar` Todos ellos tienen **7 caracteres**. Puedes probar tus datos usando [esta función](http://rextester.com/JPQG72040). Es muy probable que en ellos hayan caracteres ocultos o que valgan por dos.